# How to populate a ToolStripComboBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I find it hard binding data to a `ToolStripComboBox`. It seems it doesn't have the `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` properties.

How to bind it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To access the wrapped combobox in toolstripcombobox and gain access to its `ValueMember/DisplayMember/DataSource` you have to write something like this:

```
ToolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.ValueMember = "YourValueField";
```

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't set `ToolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.DataSource = null`

If you set `ToolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.DataSource = null` then you can try

```
ToolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.DataSource = null
ToolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.DisplayMember= "DisplayName"
ToolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.ValueMember = "Value"
ToolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.DataSource = dataSource
```